# Workaround for Tumbling window trigger dependency limit of 5

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a situation where I have 10 thumbing window triggers that ingest telemetry into a database.  When all of those triggers have succeeded I want to run a pipeline that depends on all of these inputs.

The tumbling window dependency feature is perfect.  Except it has a limit of 5 dependencies.

Any suggestion on how to work around this limit?

This limit seems very small for complex data situations.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use the API to the get the status of the trigger run .
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/trigger-runs/query-by-factory

Other thought right now trigger 11 is dependent on all the trigger 1-10 something like
[image]
Can you do something like
[image]